# Any reason why `TextInputLayout` would use style colors to draw a cursor but not the underline?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, android-textinputedittext

I am trying to set the underline color of a `TextInputEditText` in a `TextInputLayout`. When setting `colorControlActivated` to the desired color, the cursor changes color but the underline does not respond.

I have tried:

- Creating a style with `colorControlHighlight`, `colorControlNormal`, and `colorControlActivated` defined. Setting widget themes both in the layout file and in the manifest.
- Setting the background of the input field to a drawable with the underline manually drawn in.

Here is the style defined in values/themes.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.DetailItem" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#0000ff</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff00ff</item>
</style>
```

And the theme applied:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DetailItem"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceBody2"
        tools:text="Name" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I would expect the underline of the `TextInputEditText` to change color to `colorControlActivated` when focused, and `colorControlNormal` when not focused. However, no matter what, the underline color remains black when not focused, and `colorPrimary` when focused. However, the cursor does change to `colorControlActivated` when the field is focused, so the widget is recognizing the style I have defined, but it is not using the style colors to draw the underline.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a FilledBox the underline color is defined by **`boxStrokeColor`** attribute.

It is the default selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

You can set a custom selector or you can override the `colorOnSurface` and `colorPrimary` color with

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DetailItem"
    ...>
```

where:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.DetailItem">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
    ....
  </style>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. When setting `boxStrokeColor` to a custom selector or even just a color, I am not seeing a change. I do see a change when using `colorOnSurface`, however this also changes the label color.

Comment: It seems like I am unable to interact with any of the `TextInputLayout` color theming attributes. The only times I have seen change related to the `TextInputLayout` colors is when setting a color such as `colorOnSurface` which the default theming attributes pull from (like in the `boxStrokeColor` default selector you mentioned)

Comment: Are you using the version 1.1.0-beta01?

Comment: `1.1.0-alpha06`

Comment: After updating to `1.1.0-beta01`, I am still seeing the problem

Comment: Quite strange. Using the attributes in the layout you shouldn't have issue with theme or colors.

Comment: Agreed, strange. Thanks for your help. I'll update if I ever figure out what's wrong.